# Wrong Date Recieve in .net api controller from angular

Tags: c#, .net, angular

im posting date as below from angular
Mon Dec 20 1993 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

but .net api controller recieve
19-dec-1993

it make -1 date automatically

dont know how to resolve

Comment: "dont know how to resolve" -- I don't either...because I don't know what your code looks like. Post your code and we can go from there. [mcve]

Comment: Use something like toUTCString() on the date object in angular before you send it to net core. Also store the date as utc in net core. Send and receive as UTC, then let the browser handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most likely due to a different timezone in your backend as suggested on the other answer.

You could try sending the date to the backend without the timezone with something like

```
var yourDate = new Date();
yourDate.toLocaleString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your backend also using same timezone? Please check that in asp controller maybe timezone is different that's why there is a one day gap.